# ORACLE SQL - How to add commas and dollar sign to a table value

Tags: sql, oracle

For this, I am trying to display my table values in a currency format, here's my code;

```
SELECT SNAME,
        (SAL) AS MONTHLY,
        ROUND((SAL/22), 2) AS DAILY,
        ROUND(((SAL/22)/8), 2) AS HOURLY
        FROM STAFF
            WHERE BRANCHID = 30
```

This is what I get;

```
SNAME         MONTHLY      DAILY     HOURLY
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
BATES            1800      81.82      10.23
```

This is what I want;

```
SNAME         MONTHLY      DAILY     HOURLY
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
BATES            $1,800.00      $81.82      $10.23
```

So pretty much format the values with a '$' sign and automatically add a ',' where appropriate.

I am very new to this so I apologize if this sounds dumb in any way :p

Comment: Look into using `TO_CHAR`: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This nature can be derived using the NLS setting.

You can alter the `NLS_LANGUAGE` and `NLS_TERRITORY` for your session and use the TO_CHAR function to achieve the desired behavior as follows:

```
SQL> alter session set NLS_LANGUAGE=AMERICAN;

Session altered.

SQL> alter session set NLS_TERRITORY=AMERICA;

Session altered.

SQL>
SQL> SELECT TO_CHAR(1800,'L99G999D00') salary FROM DUAL;

SALARY
--------------------
           $1,800.00

SQL>
```

You can see current NLS setting using following Views:

1. `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`
2. `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`
3. `NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS`

Comment: What if I have ROUND etc. before a table title, like you mentioned, TO_CHAR(1800, 'L99G99D00'), is there a way to swap the '1800' with the table name like SAL that I've rounded up?

Comment: You can play around with it. Definitely!!